# Overlaying text on youtube embed iframe [html and css]

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube

I'm working an existing Wordpress website to add youtube video display section. This would be a section with sub section containing a youtube iframe embed.

Each sub section will contain a short clickable text that will partly overlay on the iframe section.

To do this, Ive created a custom post type for youtube videos, which will have custom fields (used acf for custom field). I have also created a shortcode that would be used to display the videos on pages and post.

**My problem** I can not get the text to overlay on the youtube video with a background color as its background color gets over written.

Here is my code

```
add_shortcode( 'video_section', 'video_section_shortcode' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'video_section_shortcode' ) ) {
    function video_section_shortcode( ){

        /**
         * show 4 video on page reload.
         
         */
            $args = array(  
                'post_type' => 'slidevideo',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 4, 
                'orderby' => 'rand', 
                'order' => 'rand', 
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                $embed_link = str_replace('.com/watch?v=', '.com/embed/', do_shortcode('[acf field="youtube_video_link"]')).'?modestbranding=1';
                ?>
                <div class="custom-video-section">
                    <div class="custom-video">              
                        <div class="custom-video-iframe">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $embed_link; ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-iframe-overlay">
                            <a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="link"]'); ?>">
                                <div class="overlay-text">
                                    <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="overlay_text"]'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>

                <style>
                    .custom-video-section {
                        width: 100%;
                        

                    }

                    .custom-video{
                        width: 50%;
                        position: relative;
                        float: left;
                        padding: 10px;
                    }
                    
                    .custom-iframe-overlay {
                        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255,0.9);
                        
                        padding: 10px;
                        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                        margin-top : -50px;
                        z-index: 99999;
                    }
                    
                
                    
                </style>



                <?php                                
               
            endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata(); 
        

         return;
       

    }

    
}
```

Here is what I currently have https://prnt.sc/qyA9PrHWqyEM

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try z-index with !important in CSS.

.custom-iframe-overlay {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255,0.9);

```
                    padding: 10px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                    margin-top : -50px;
                    z-index: 99999 **!important**;
                }
```